# Resolve cropping keeping a part of a screen

Tags: davinci-resolve

I am trying to crop a video in Resolve while keeping and moving a part of the cropped scene.

So the original footage is:

[image]

I want to do this:

[image]

With a final result of:

[image]

The only way I know to do this is to duplicate the movies in the `Edit` tab and then crop and transform. Is there another way that does not require to duplicate the entire clip?

Comment: Is the text in its own layer?

Answer (score 0):

Which approach is easiest depends on your source material. If your source consists of two layers; a text layer and a background, then you’d crop the background and reposition the text. If the text is “burnt” into the background, on the other hand, or if the area you’re trying to keep isn’t text at all, the best approach is to 1) crop the background as described above, then 2) create a duplicate copy of the background layer described in 1, place the new one above the old one in the layer stack (i.e., old on V1, new on V2), and then crop the upper layer more tightly than the lower one.

Comment: The source material is a single video file, no layers, no text. In that case, if I understood correctly, what you said is the way I know: to duplicate the video layer and use crop and transform.

Comment: Duplicate, crop and transform is the way to go if you only need to keep a simple, rectangular area, and it doesn’t need to move with the background. For more complex situations, look into the “patch replacement” effect, which is like photoshop’s clone stamp tool.